# REPLACE function for replacing part of string in specific column

Tags: sql, teradata-sql-assistant

I have written the following code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM BMD_MI_OPS.DBH_TELEFONIE
WHERE cast(DATUM_TIJD as date) BETWEEN 1180212 AND 1180217;

UPDATE BMD_MI_OPS.DBH_TELEFONIE 
SET QUEUE_NAAM = REPLACE(QUEUE_NAAM, '_DVB', '');
```

This should take all columns of the table `BMD_MI_OPS.DBH_TELEFONIE` within the given period in the WHERE statement. Then it should erase every _DVB that appears in the column `QUEUE_NAAM`. For example, `VQ_PAR_EC_00_DVB` should become `VQ_PAR_EC_00`.

I guess I am doing something wrong, any help on how to get this done would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Your statements are not linked, if you want to update your data you need to add a `WHERE` clause in your `UPDATE`

For example :

```
UPDATE BMD_MI_OPS.DBH_TELEFONIE 
SET QUEUE_NAAM = REPLACE(QUEUE_NAAM, '_DVB', '')
WHERE CAST(DATUM_TIJD AS DATE) BETWEEN 1180212 AND 1180217;
```

Selecting rows before your update has no impact on your update, it' just a `SELECT`

Comment: So where should I put the select function?

Comment: Why do you want a `SELECT` ? You will need it to get the final result, so use it after not before.

Comment: I ran the code above, so without select. It says that it expects something in between '=' and 'REPLACE'

Comment: This problem come from your default query. Your job to change this, just don't forget : `UPDATE` clause for update data and `SELECT` clause for get the result.